# What is the string concatenation operator in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, string-concatenation

What is the string concatenation operator in Oracle SQL?

Are there any "interesting" features I should be careful of?

(This seems obvious, but I couldn't find a previous question asking it).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm

Answer (score 285, accepted):

It is `||`, for example:

```
select 'Mr ' || ename from emp;
```

The only "interesting" feature I can think of is that `'x' || null` returns `'x'`, not `null` as you might perhaps expect.

Comment: I'd expect null from a logical operation... not sure I'd ever thought about a string operation.

Comment: Well of course Oracle treats null and '' as the same, and 'x' || '' = 'x' makes sense.  But if you think of null as "undefined" or "unknown" then 'x' || null could be any string beginning with 'x' and so is itself "unknown"!

Comment: `||` in Oracle is not a logical operator, therefore, `'x'||null` returns `x`.

Comment: @ipip: I am confused - if by "logical operator" you mean operators like `AND`, `NOT` etc. then of course `||` is not a logical operator.  But what does that have to due with `'x'||null` returning `x`?  `n+null` returns null, so is `+` a logical operator?

Comment: Oracle's handling of null in concatenation is non-standard in that it is different to the SQL92 spec (and Postgres) - see http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/921.1144705646@sss.pgh.pa.us

Answer (score 70):

There's also concat, but it doesn't get used much

```
select concat('a','b') from dual;
```

Comment: this is way better than the || symbol. using || is just confusing as per other language's use of ||.

Comment: I prefer `concat()` to `||` for clarity.

Comment: This is what I needed. Wanted to use it in expression  AND REGEXP_LIKE(CONCAT(

Comment: Agreed for clarity, but || has the advantage to allow more then 2 fields easily

Comment: `CONCAT` is also compatible with other DBMSes (at least MySQL and Postgres).

Comment: Odd that it didn't occur to the ANSI SQL committee that anyone might need to concatenate more than two things. (Same goes for the geniuses at Oracle who came up with `nvl()`.)

Comment: `CONCAT` is also [available in Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and onwards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx).  CONCAT, though nonstandard, is definitely the way to go if you want your code to be portable. (`||` is the actual ANSI standard operator, though you wouldn't know it by looking at the support for it!)

Comment: Unfortunatly CONCAT() accepts only two arguments. You can concatenate indefinite numbre of strings using ||

Comment: You can actually use CONCAT() on more than two strings, it just gets more ugly and confusing: `CONCAT('a',CONCAT('b','c'))`

Answer (score 19):

I would suggest concat when dealing with 2 strings, and || when those strings are more than 2:

```
select concat(a,b)
  from dual
```

or

```
  select 'a'||'b'||'c'||'d'
        from dual
```

Comment: sorry I realise this was 2 years ago, but why would you prefer `concat(a,b)` over `a||b`?

Comment: || shorter, more flexible, and simple.  Look at his select statement.

Answer (score 7):

```
DECLARE
     a      VARCHAR2(30);
     b      VARCHAR2(30);
     c      VARCHAR2(30);
 BEGIN
      a  := ' Abc '; 
      b  := ' def ';
      c  := a || b;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c);  
   END;
```

output:: Abc  def

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways to concatenate Strings in `Oracle SQL`. Either using `CONCAT` function or `||` operator.

`CONCAT` function allows you to concatenate two strings together

```
SELECT CONCAT( string1, string2 ) FROM dual;
```

Since `CONCAT` function will only **allow you to concatenate two values together**. If you want to concatenate more values than two, you can n**est multiple CONCAT function** calls.

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT('A', 'B'),'C') FROM dual;
```

An alternative to using the `CONCAT` function would be to use the **||** operator

```
SELECT 'My Name' || 'My Age' FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `CONCAT(CONCAT(,),)` worked for me when concatenating more than two strings.

My problem required working with date strings (only) and creating `YYYYMMDD` from `YYYY-MM-DD` as follows (i.e. without converting to date format):

```
CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTR(DATECOL,1,4),SUBSTR(DATECOL,6,2)),SUBSTR(DATECOL,9,2)) AS YYYYMMDD
```