# Sql adding a string and number and displaying it as a single column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to take a column that stores a id # for a webpage on a site and store it with the full url.

If the Article ID is 5. I want it to store return something like this

```
<a href="http://website.com/5">5</a>
```

What I am trying to do is combine a string put in the search and a number to make a URL for the column. I know this syntax is incorrect but I can not find anyway on how to do it.

```
SELECT
CASE                                                                        
WHEN m_tableFoo.articleId = '0' THEN                                
    'Not Applicable'                                                    
ELSE '<a href="http://website.com/'+m_tableFoo.articleId+'/">'+m_tableFoo.articleId+'</a>' 
END AS articleID
from m_tableFoo
```

I have tried searching the web and Stack Overflow, but I am not sure if my search wording is incorrect or my description.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278189/what-is-the-string-concatenation-operator-in-oracle

Comment: You will need to convert the articleID to a string, and also the concatenation operator in Oracle is `||`

Comment: thanks I'll take a look at that, that seems to be the correct wording.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

oracle uses `||` for concatenation, not `+`. You will probably also need to `TO_CHAR` the article ids

Comment: Just to complete this statement: `||` is the SQL standard for string concatenation and besides MySQL and Microsoft all DBMS vendor comply with that.