# Can't add a string to the end of a string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query:

```
SELECT distinct
  substr(p1.name,-1) as index_
  p2.value as value        
FROM pks p  
  LEFT JOIN Parameter p1 on p1.ID=p.id AND p1.NAME like '%TFrom%'
  LEFT JOIN Parameter p2 on p2.ID=p.id AND p2.NAME like '%TFrom%' + substr(p1.name,-1)

WHERE p.type='singer'
```

What I want to do is to add the `index_` value to the end of the `p2.NAME` string.
Sometimes the `index_` is `(null)`, but I don't belive that It's a problem, as when it's an empty string it just should pass without adding somthing to the `p2_NAME` string

In SQL server it can be done by adding this after the Join:

```
+(SUBSTRING(p1.NAME,[length], len(p1.PA_NAME)) )
```

But in Oracle it won't add a string to string. I'm sure that I'm missing somthing really small.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278189/what-is-the-string-concatenation-operator-in-oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concatenation in Oracle is done with `||`:

```
p2.NAME like '%TFrom%' || substr(p1.name,-1)
```

Comment: It's not working. :( I'm getting an invalid identifier error

Comment: You have something different wrong. The above syntax is ok.

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate strings with either `||` or `concat`:

```
select last_name || '''s job category is ' || job_id
FROM employees 
WHERE employee_id = 152;
```

or

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(last_name, '''s job category is '), job_id) "Job" 
FROM employees 
WHERE employee_id = 152;
```