# How to replace first two characters of a column with another value in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table in the following way.

```
TAX_ID_ID CUST_ID TAX_ID_TYP_CD TAX_ID_NO TAX_ID_DRV_UPCS_NO
1005004 2005004 ssn 100000006 100000006
1005006 2005006 ssn 100000007 100000007
1005009 2005009 ssn 100000008 100000008
1005012 2005012 ssn 100000009 100000009
1005014 2005014 ssn 100000010 100000010
1005017 2005017 ssn 100000011 100000011
```

I wanted to replace first two characters of TAX_ID_NO, TAX_ID_DRV_UPCS_NO with 25 in place of 10. The columns data type is varchar2. What would be the update query for this

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I have mentioned it already, they are varchar2 types. I have tried with replace function, but didn't workout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do your need.

**[Replace](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php)**

**[Substring](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php)**

**[String Concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278189/what-is-the-string-concatenation-operator-in-oracle)**

```
replace(TAX_ID_NO,TAX_ID_NO,'25'||substr( TAX_ID_NO, 3,length(TAX_ID_NO)-2))
replace(TAX_ID_DRV_UPCS_NO ,TAX_ID_DRV_UPCS_NO ,'25'||substr( TAX_ID_DRV_UPCS_NO , 3,length(TAX_ID_NO)-2))
```

**Edit**

Finally you have to `Update` the table as

```
UPDATE TABLE
   SET TAX_ID_NO = replace(TAX_ID_NO,TAX_ID_NO,'25'||substr( TAX_ID_NO, 3,length(TAX_ID_NO)-2)),
   SET TAX_ID_DRV_UPCS_NO = replace(TAX_ID_DRV_UPCS_NO ,TAX_ID_DRV_UPCS_NO ,'25'||substr( TAX_ID_DRV_UPCS_NO , 3,length(TAX_ID_NO)-2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
select 
  '25'||substr(TAX_ID_NO, 3), 
  '25'||substr(TAX_ID_DRV_UPCS_NO, 3) 
From YourTable;
```

Update your table using

```
update YourTable
set TAX_ID_NO='25'||substr(TAX_ID_NO, 2),
    TAX_ID_DRV_UPCS_NO='25'||substr(TAX_ID_DRV_UPCS_NO, 2);
```