# Oracle multiple column single Alias

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to select multiple columns and concatenate them in one column with a plus sign and one space on both sides of this plus sign in Oracle 11.2.0.1.0

```
SELECT ename AS Emplyee_name , deptno AS Department_Number , comm+" + " + sal AS This_Month_Comm_and_sal FROM emp WHERE ename = 'AHMAD';
```

I am getting this error

> ORA-00904: " + ": invalid identifier

same is done in this w3schools tutorial [W3schools SQL tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_alias_column2&ss=-1)

how can I achieve the same result in ORACLE?

Comment: Don't use w3schools for reference that site is full of errors. Claiming that strings are concatenated in SQL using `+` is just one of them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the string concatenation operator in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278189/what-is-the-string-concatenation-operator-in-oracle)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string concatenation operator is `||` in Oracle:
Single quotes must be used here.

```
SELECT 
    ename AS Emplyee_name , 
    deptno AS Department_Number , 
    TO_CHAR(comm) || ' + ' || TO_CHAR(sal) AS This_Month_Comm_and_sal 
FROM emp 
WHERE ename = 'AHMAD';
```

Comment: I am Still getting the same error even after using || for concatenation.

Comment: `||` is the string concatenation operator in *standard SQL* btw: there is no such thing as PSQL in Oracle. It's either PL/SQL - which this is not - or simply SQL.

Comment: @Ahmadzkn If `comm` and `sal` are numeric types use `TO_CHAR` to convert to strings.

Comment: @DStanley 'TO_CHAR' did the trick also the double quotes had to be replaced with single quotes to achieve the desired result. Thank you so so much :)