# Oracle LIKE-wildcard in inner SELECT query

Tags: sql, t-sql, oracle11g

In SQL Server T-SQL I used to use the scenario like this

```
SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE sometable.eng LIKE (SELECT tmpcolumn FROM tmptable WHERE tmpID = @counter) + '%';
```

How to pass LIKE (subquery) + '%' in Oracle correcly?
Does it actually work for Oracle 11g+ or not?

```
.. smth LIKE (SELECT .. FROM ..) + '%';
```

The underscore _ for fixed length doesn't fit my needs, so % only.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278189/what-is-the-string-concatenation-operator-in-oracle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle uses `||` for string concatenation, not `+`. So it should be:

```
smth LIKE (SELECT .. FROM ..) || '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like such an odd formulation.  Just as a note, I would write the query as:

```
SELECT ..
FROM ..
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tmptable
              WHERE tmpID = @Counter AND
                    sometable.eng LIKE tmpcolumn || '%'
             );
```

Putting a subquery between the keyword `LIKE` and the wildcard makes the query harder to read (at least for me).