# 'PLS-00103 Encountered the symbol "+" ...' error when trying to concatenate some strings in a trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a SQL table where a particular `record ID` (the primary key) could have several `Contact ID`s. I want to create a trigger where each time a new row is added, it will check whether the `record ID` exists, and if it does it will add the new `Contact ID` to the current `Contact ID` field separated by a comma (to essentially create a list). So for multiple `Contact ID`s the field could become:

`Contact123, Contact456, Contact999`

To do this, I've written the following trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TRIGGER "TEST_INSERT" BEFORE
   INSERT ON "TEST_INSERT" REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD FOR EACH ROW DECLARE REC_COUNT INTEGER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(*)
   INTO REC_COUNT
   FROM TEST_INSERT
   WHERE RECORDID = :NEW.RECORDID;
   IF REC_COUNT > 0 THEN
      CONTACTID + ', ' + :NEW.CONTACTID AS CONTACTID;   --This is the line where I'm getting the error
   END IF;
END;
```

I'm getting an error for the `+` sign as well as the `AS` operation. Am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Thanks

Comment: Oracle strings are concatenated usually using `||` operator instead of `+`

Comment: [The concatenation operator is ||](http://stackoverflow.com/q/278189/266304); you also need to assign your concatenated string to something. What you're doing doesn't really make sense though. If you insert a new contact, you want to change that new value to be an old value *and* the new value? Or you want to change the insert into an update so you only have a single row, breaking normalisation? You almost certainly don't want to do that, and if you do you can't use a trigger. You mentioned a PK; are the contacts in a child table?

Comment: @tvm: that is nothing specific to Oracle. That's the operator defined in the SQL standard.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I have tried it with both + and || and they both come out as the same PL-00103 error. Alex, I am trying to add the new value of `CONTACTID` to the one on the row that I have matched the `RECORDID` against. I want to end up with a list of Contact IDs rather than having a separate row for each. In Javascript, for example, I would do this as `contactId=contactId+", "+newContactId`, which is what I'm trying to replicate.

Comment: If you want to append a new value to a value in an existing row, then you need to update that row, not insert a new one. You can 'upsert' with a merge statement, but not from a trigger - use merge instead of insert in the first place. I'd really question your approach anyway though; you're denormalising the data - why not have a separate table with one row for each recordid/contactid combination? What will you do when you want to change or remove a contact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change an insert into an update in a trigger. There are several issues in your erroring line anyway:

```
CONTACTID + ', ' + :NEW.CONTACTID AS CONTACTID;
```

As well as using + instead of || for concatenation, you are not assigning that new value to a variable - `CONACTID` doesn't exist in the PL/SQL scope you're working in, and although you could potentially do the concatenation as part of an update (without the `AS` clause either), you can't do that update inside the before-insert for-each-row insert trigger as you'd hit a mutating table error, and even if that worked the insert would still happen as well.

It looks like you really want to do an 'upsert' - update an existing record if it exists, or add a new record if it does not. In Oracle you do that with [the `merge` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606). Here's an example, which I've wrapped in a procedure just to make the calls cleaner and reduce duplication - it would normally just be plain SQL rather than embedded in PL/SQL:

```
create table test_merge (recordid number primary key,
  contactid varchar2(4000));

create procedure p_merge(p_recordid number, p_contactid number) as
begin
  merge into test_merge t
  using (select p_recordid as recordid, p_contactid as contactid from dual) x
  on (t.recordid = x.recordid)
  when matched then
    update set contactid = t.contactid ||','|| x.contactid
  when not matched then
    insert (recordid, contactid) values (x.recordid, x.contactid);
end;
/

exec p_merge (1, 123);
exec p_merge (1, 234);
exec p_merge (1, 456);
exec p_merge (2, 567);

select * from test_merge;

  RECORDID CONTACTID          
---------- --------------------
         1 123,234,456         
         2 567
```

But storing a comma-separated list of denormalised data is not a good idea. You need to think about how you will modify that value (if you have to remove a contact, say, or want them to be ordered) and how you will use the values in the string - assuming each contact ID is a reference out to another table you'd have to deconstruct the string to do the join. You're also limited but the maximum size of a string column.

It would be much better to have a separate table linking the record and contact IDs:

```
create table test_parent (recordid number primary key);
create table test_child (recordid number references test_parent(recordid),
  contactid number);

insert into test_parent (recordid) values (1);
insert into test_parent (recordid) values (2);
insert into test_child (recordid, contactid) values (1, 123);
insert into test_child (recordid, contactid) values (1, 234);
insert into test_child (recordid, contactid) values (1, 456);
insert into test_child (recordid, contactid) values (2, 567);
```

If you want to see the comma-separated list then generate that when you need it, with string aggregation. 11g and upwards have [the built-in `listagg` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm) to do this:

```
select p.recordid,
  listagg(c.contactid, ',') within group (order by c.contactid) as contactids
from test_parent p
left join test_child c on c.recordid = p.recordid
group by p.recordid
order by p.recordid;

  RECORDID CONTACTIDS         
---------- --------------------
         1 123,234,456         
         2 567
```

Comment: Excellently explained. I see your point about data normalisation - will look at implementing multiple tables as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server and Microsoft Access you concatenate with the +, But in oracle you use || to concatenate and in mySQL you use the CONCAT function. Are you sure that in your situation you are using the right concatenate (If I remember correctly PLS means it's an oracle error, so you should be using || instead of +)?

Comment: `||` is the concatenation operator defined by the SQL **standard** it's nothing Oracle specific. Microsoft simply decided to ignore that standard  even though it existed **long** before Access or SQL Server were created.