# Putting in additional, temporary text for results in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to put in an additional word in a specific column of results for a query. I've got the query fine, but I can only find how to name a specific column within a table, and not the data shown within the column, and can't find the proper query online.

I want to get the data in the column to show '50 People', instead of just '50'.

For reference this is what I've got at the moment

```
SELECT *
FROM SCREEN
WHERE SCREENID IN ('S1','S3')
AND BRANCHID IN ('B1','B4')
AND SCREENCAPACITY NOT LIKE '%120%'
```

Comment: But why do you want to do that? Show us sample table data - both before and after the change.

Comment: Are you asking how to do string concatenation in Oracle? That wouldn't help anyway if you use `SELECT *`.

Comment: Perhaps `concat(columnname,  ' people')`, or the ANSI SQL way `columnname || ' people'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the string concatenation operator in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/278189/266304). But as already said, you can't use `*` - which is bad practice anyway. You have to list all the column names, and manipulate the one that has that value. (And why are you comparing `screencapacity`, which is hopefully a number, as a string; and why `not like`? Are you trying to only exclude 120, or also 1201, 1120, etc.?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose Your SCREENID is 'S1', 'S3' and you want to show 'S1 Screen' and 'S3 Screen'.

```
SELECT CONCAT(SCREENID, ' Screen') AS RX
FROM SCREEN
WHERE SCREENID IN ('S1','S3')
AND BRANCHID IN ('B1','B4')
AND SCREENCAPACITY NOT LIKE '%120%'
```

Comment: "+"  is not a valid concatination operator in oracle

Comment: You would also need to specify the table name (or an alias) before `*`, i.e. `SELECT SCREEN.*, ...`; and you'll get the original value as well as the concatenated one, which probably isn't useful. Also `convert` isn't right for Oracle either.

Comment: Sorry don't see oracle. I think CONCAT will be fine.

Comment: CONCAT was the one, all fixed now. Thanks so much!