# Combining two columns of a table and returning it as a single column separated by a character

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using oracle sql developer for the first time. I want to create a view with two columns of a table combined and seperated by a slash.
I have done this in ssms but when I write the same code for sql dev it returns me problems like 'the specified number is invalid.

```
SELECT ID AS W_ID, CAST(data1 AS VARCHAR)+' - '+data2 AS W_CODE, +data3 AS W_TEXT
FROM table1
WHERE data3=1;
```

how can I translate this query in Oracle ?

Comment: [What is the string concatenation operator in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/278189/266304)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle uses the standard `||` operator for string concatenation, not `+`:

```
SELECT ID AS W_ID,
       (data1 ||  ' - ' || data2) AS W_CODE,
      data3 AS W_TEXT
FROM table1
WHERE data3 = 1;
```

Casting to a string is unnecessary.  Oracle will do that automatically.  If you do, `TO_CHAR()` is the more colloquial method in Oracle, because it lets you control the format for numbers and dates.

I don't understand the purpose of `+`, so I removed it.  Perhaps you want `abs()`?

Comment: it returns me the error missing right parenthesis.. --- edit: the right parenthesis goes before the AS! 
Thank you very much!

Comment: @helloandroiddevelopers - you don't need the parentheses at all.