# Concate columns using oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

C.ADDRESS1 || ',' || C.ADDRESS2 || ',' || C.ADDRESS3

```
pa.address_line_1,
pa.address_line_2,
pa.address_line_3 from per_addresses_f pa ;
```

how to join three column as single address column with oracle SQL concatenate

How to write query for joining 3 columns as single column?

Comment: As you have done in your question? I don't understand what you are asking...?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. All as formatted text, not images.

Comment: pa.address_line_1,

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit the question instead. Add several rows of data. Are there any columns that may have NULL values?

Comment: pa.address_line_2, pa.address_line_3 are from table per_addresses_f pa. how can concatenate this three columns into single column as Emergency Address

Comment: Please [**edit your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58077561/edit) to add your data and expected result as formatted text. I still don't understand quite what you need as your question already shows what you need to do.

Comment: @Likhitha I added in my answer column names you stated. I also added your desired alias. The concatenation you stated in your question is correct in principle, you just had to implement it inside SQL query

Comment: This kind of questions are already answered, I believe more than once. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278189/what-is-the-string-concatenation-operator-in-oracle. People to often ask questions without trying to do some research before. Show us the query you have tried to do and what is the problem with it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the string concatenation operator in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278189/what-is-the-string-concatenation-operator-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1):

You can write the concatenation as you've written it, but you have to make sure that all the components are strings. If some of them isn't, put it in `TO_CHAR` function. It's also good to put an alias to your result of concatenated columns:

```
SELECT C.ADDRESS1 || ',' || C.ADDRESS2 || ',' || C.ADDRESS3  as concatenated_adress
  FROM your_table c
```

**EDIT :** After question was edited with concrete columns that are used, table name and with desired alias stated in question columns:

```
SELECT pa.address_line_1 || ',' || pa.address_line_2 || ',' || pa.address_line_3
         as "Emergency Address"
  FROM per_addresses_f pa
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
CONCAT(C.ADDRESS1, ',', C.ADDRESS2, ',', C.ADDRESS3) AS newColumnName
```

Comment: Oracle's [`concat()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CONCAT.html) only takes two arguments; it would have to be nested calls.

Comment: This is not right. Oracle concat() takes only two arguments

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT firstname ||' '|| lastname AS employee_name FROM employee;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try nested CONCAT assuming all address_line fields have char datatype:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(pa.address_line_1,','),CONCAT(pa.address_line_2,',')),pa.address_line_3) AS address FROM per_addresses_f pa
```

But clearly pipe operator as suggested by @Goran Kutlaca is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to Concate the column in BIP.

  1.

> SELECT pa.address_line_1 || ',' || pa.address_line_2 || ',' ||
>   pa.address_line_3
>            as "Emergency Address"   FROM per_addresses_f pa

  2.

> SELECT
>   CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(pa.address_line_1,','),CONCAT(pa.address_line_2,',')),pa.address_line_3)
>   AS address FROM per_addresses_f pa

  3.

> select
>   CONCAT(pa.address_line_1,',',pa.address_line_2,',',pa.address_line_3)
>   as address FROM per_addresses_f pa