# SQL concatenation (new to SQL)

Tags: sql, concatenation, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to concatinate the first name and last name from the worker table as a full name. It's working, but there is no space between the first and last names. For example: `JohnDoe` instead of `John Doe`. I tried adding an additional `' '` in the concatenation, but that just kills the code and it will not run.

Here is my code.

```
SELECT WORKER_ID,
       CONCAT(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) AS FULL_NAME,
       CITY
FROM WORKER
WHERE CITY NOT IN ('Hinsdale', 'Glencoe', 'Wilmette', 'Chicago');
```

The code I tried was:

```
SELECT WORKER_ID,
       CONCAT(FIRST_NAME, ' ', LAST_NAME) AS FULL_NAME,
       CITY
FROM WORKER
WHERE CITY NOT IN ('Hinsdale', 'Glencoe', 'Wilmette', 'Chicago');
```

But that did not work. How can I fix this?

Comment: In Oracle, it's not allowed to use `CONCAT` with more than two arguments. Just use `||` instead: `...FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME...` See also this question: [Concat strings in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278189/what-is-the-string-concatenation-operator-in-oracle)

Comment: @JonasMetzler It worked thanks! I had to also remove the parenthesis for it to work